# georeference and orthorectification of aerial photos

Tags: grass-gis, georeferencing, orthorectification, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I am trying to process photos taken with a tetracam ADC micro camera placed on a UAV.

I have GPS coordinates and mavlink logs providing roll, pitch and yaw of the UAV.

I am having a real hard time georeferencing and orthorectifying the pics using tools as ossim or grass.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4):

You can use GRASS GIS 6 for orthorectification of aerial photos (UAV should work the same). See for related instructions:

- http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Orthorectification_digital_camera
- [Orthorectification chapter](http://www.grassbook.org/sample2nd/grassbook_2nd_2004_chapter10_aerial.pdf) from the GRASS GIS book

Answer (score 4):

Photoscan maybe a better choice. You could download a 30 days trial version from http://www.agisoft.com/