# aerial photo to georeferenced mosaic with X,Y, Z, omega, phi, kappa

Tags: qgis, mosaic, aerial-photography

It's worth mentioning that I'm not very experienced.

I have a bunch of aerial photos acquired with digital camera. Photos were taken by night to detect streetlights. Each has 60% forward overlap. I also have file with photo_id, GPS time, X, Y, Z, omega, phi and kappa.

I would like to georeference each photo (creating any world file out of text file) and than create mosaic for further investigation.

Any idea how to do that in QGIS?

Comment: Have you searched for drone mapping tools? there are lots of options that may suit including Open drone Map, Maps made easy and VSFM.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you not only want to georeference the images but you also want to orthorectify them, meaning the elimintation of distortions. However if you only want to georeference them you could use [QGIS](http://qgis.org/de/site/). In the other case you should have a look at [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/). For your convenience it's also contained in the QGIS installation.

Nevertheless the rectification process is a quite complex task and should try to find some sources to get into the topic. Maybe you could have a look on the links given in the related post [georeference and orthorectification of aerial photos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95514/georeference-and-orthorectification-of-aerial-photos).